# Soundcloud embedded HTML theme_color option not working

Tags: html, embed, soundcloud

I am embedding Soundcloud HTML code in a web page to show the audio player. Previewing in Safari 5.1.4 on Mac and running in a webview in my iPhone app (which should behave the same as Safari) the embed parameter "theme_color" does not work.

E.g.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/44200324&auto_play=true&color=915f33&theme_color=00FF00"></iframe>
```

Anyone know why or a workaround? I want to be able to "colourise" the main look of the player from grey to another colour.

Comment: From what I can see it does affect the color, but mainly the play/pause button.

Comment: If you want to have full control,go to the documentation here:http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player

Comment: @agam360. The iframe color option affects the colour of the play button only. Yes just started looking at the custom player docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have custom colors using flash object:

```
<object height="81" width="100%"> 
    <param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F32678080&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=00cc00&amp;theme_color=111111"></param> 
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> 
    <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F32678080&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=00cc00&amp;theme_color=111111" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> 
</object>
```

For the list of available params take a look at:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget